# Querying Archive Class with REST API of ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, archiving

I would like to know if there is a way to access the archive class through a Map Service of ArcGIS Server.

I have a Map Service with feature class stored in a SDE GeoDatabase with Archiving and Versionning enable.

Is it possible to query the Archive Class in order to retrieve features at a perticular moment using the Feature Access or Mapping capabilities through the REST API?

When I try to publish a Map Service containing an Archive Class to ArcGIS Server I have an error saying: `Layer's data source is not registered with the geodatabase (Feature Service)`.

Comment: Are you able to publish other feature layers in the geodatabase in the same service? I'm not familiar with archiving but I'm familiar with that error.

Comment: Yes, I am able. With more investigations, it seems that Feature Access cannot be enabled when an Archive Class is present in the Map Service. I suppose to prevent any modification of it. So what I did is to publish two map services, one with Feature Access and the Feature Class, and the other without with only the Archive Class in it.

Comment: Have you considered writing an arcpy script that does this, and then publishing that as a GP service?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall that migh be a good idea! Thank you for this advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the posterity I post the solution suggested in the comment of `Below The Radar` as an answer as it helps me.

When publishing a map service the capability `Feature Access` cannot be enabled when an Archive Class is present in the Map Service.

This doesn't mean you can't query features in published Archive Class. You can still query the Archive Class if you enable the `Query`operation from the capability `Data Management`.

Comment: Were you able to filter/view by GDB_FROM_DATE and GDB_TO_DATE?  My archive feature service does not provide any history information.  The feature count is the same as the feature class it archives.  Is there any utility in exposing the archive class via REST?  How would one go about detecting deleted features?

Comment: For your first question "Were you able to filter/view by GDB_FROM_DATE and GDB_TO_DATE?" yes I was. For your last question I suggest you the following [documentation page about working with archive class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/fr/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/working-directly-with-the-archive-class.htm) and the following [documentation page about the archive process](http://desktop.arcgis.com/fr/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/the-archive-process.htm). Hope it helps.

Comment: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/the-archive-process.htm is what led me to these ideas but I'm unable to query or observe GDB_*_DATE via REST (and therefore unable to detect deletes).  Thanks for confirming it is possible.  Probably I just need to make a simple correction.